# Configure AVCodecContext structure to encode from raw PCM to u-law

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, encode, avcodec

I'm trying to encode raw PCM audio data to u-law and it's sound very weird (when it sounds...). I don't understand pretty much how to initialize my `AVCodecContext` structure (and my input `AVFrame`).

Here are my parameters:

- Input : PCM (16bits signed), MONO, 44,1kHz (sample rate) (from my Android device MIC)
- Required output : G.711 u-law, MONO, 8kHz (sample rate), 64 kbits/s (bitrate) (from my output target device's documentation)

I also know my input nb samples and this is all informations I have.

So I initialize my `AVCodecContext` like that:

```
AVCodec* pCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_MULAW);
// ...
AVCodecContext* pCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(pCodec);
// ...
// Do I need input or output params in following lines?
pCodecContext->channels = 1:
pCodecContext->channel_layout = AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO;
pCodecContext->sample_rate = 8000;
pCodecContext->bit_rate = 64000
pCodecContext->sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16;
```

And my `AVFrame`s like:

```
AVFrame* pFrame = av_frame_alloc();
pFrame->channels = 1;
pFrame->channel_layout = AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO;
pFrame->sample_rate = 44100;
pFrame->format = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16;
pFrame->nb_samples = /*my audio data samples count*/;
avcodec_fill_audio_frame(pFrame, 1, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16, /*my audio data*/, /*my audio data size*/, 0);
```

Then, I encode with `avcodec_send_frame()` and `avcodec_receive_packet()`.

So my problem is that I'm not sure if I have to put input or output desired values in different parameters. Probably I have to encode on a way then "resample" using `swresample` lib. But for now, I'm pretty sure that I don't encode properly. Any advise please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G.711 requires that your input be 8kHz mono (e.g. sample_rate of 8000). So, before passing your raw pcm audio samples to libavcodec you have to convert them to 8kHz with swresample or any other lib that can do that. If you capture your raw pcm yourself usually you can request 8kHz sampling rate from the os sound api.

I'm pretty sure on android devices you can request 8kHz audio. G.711 is such a simple codec, you don't need libavcodec for that. You can use any available [g711.c](https://github.com/quatanium/foscam-ios-sdk/blob/master/g726lib/g711.c) and simply call `linear2alaw` or `linear2ulaw` for each sample. Basically `linear2alaw` or `linear2ulaw` convert each 16-bit audio sample into a byte of g711 bitstream.

You should also ensure that you init your `AVCodecContext` properly:

```
pCodecContext->channels = 1;
pCodecContext->channel_layout = AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO; 
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand my problem and can work with that knowledge. I thought libavcodec ables to "encode" in a different sample rate! I need libavcodec because I could have other output devices with other supported formats.

Comment: Is it normal that I can't open a U-law codec (`AVCodec` encoder) with a 8kHz sample rate?

Comment: @N0un does `avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_MULAW);` return NULL?

Comment: @N0un note, also `pCodecContext->channels(1)` seems strange, it should be `pCodecContext->channels = 1;`

Comment: Sorry I fix syntax in an edit. No it not returns NULL, but `pCodec->samples_fmts()` only returns one format: `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16`. It is a problem if a pre-resample my audio sample in `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_U8`, strange isn't it? Is `pCodecContext->sample_fmt` a mandatory parameter for encoding?

Comment: Yes, g.711 it requires only `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16` on input. How is that you have `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_U8` as input?

Comment: No, I have S16 on input but I asked myself if I should have U8 instead? I mean, how can I have 64kBits/s bitrate required on output device specs? Is this bitrate important?

Comment: You have to have `S16` input. That's what you usually get from os. You feed it 8kHz of S16 (which is 128kbps), and g711 converts each 16-bit audio sample to a byte and you'll get 64kbps g711 audio bitstream. Not sure if you can omit `bit_rate = 64000` for g711, but this field is important for codecs that have multiple bitrates (like mp3).

Comment: Ok I get it now. A last question: resample using SwResample is an operation which has to be made before (with raw PCM) or after encoding? Even if it looks like I don't need it in my example...

Comment: @N0un you may need to resample your input pcm to make it acceptable by the codec. So, yes, resampling should be done before encoding.

Comment: Ok. So you can confirm that in my example, I can have PCM/S16/8kHz in input, and just need to encode it to U-law/U8/8kHz, no need to resample? But if I have 44,4kHz in input, I should resample it to 8kHz then encode, right?

Comment: Looks  ok, just change `pFrame->sample_rate = 44100;` to 8000.